# Detail in GPY argument

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I'm currently going through the proof of the GPY theorem that the EH conjecture implies that prime gaps are bounded, following the proof outlined [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1410.8400.pdf) but an confused on page 24 where it says that $\displaystyle\frac{r}{\phi(r)}\sum_{n: r \mid n} \frac{y(n)}{\phi_\omega(n/r)} \sum_{d: d/r \mid n/r}{\mu(d/r)\frac{\omega^*(d/r)d/r}{\phi(d/r)} \omega(n/d)} = r \sum_{n: r\mid n}^\prime{\frac{y(n)}{\phi(n)}}$

We know that $\phi_\omega, \omega, \omega^*$ are all multiplicative, that $\phi$ is Euler totient function and $\mu$ is the mobius function, and that $\sum^\prime$ is the sum restricted to square-free integers.
$\phi_\omega(p) = p -\omega(p)$ for primes p, extended multiplicatively onto composite numbers. $\omega(n)$ is defined to be to be the size of the set $\Omega(n)$ of congruence classes m (mod n) for which n divides some fixed polynomial $P(x)$ evaluated at m, i.e $ n \mid P(m)$ and $\omega^*(p) = \omega(p) -1$ on primes also extended multiplicatively. This feels like it should be a simple cancellation as the author does not elaborate any further. The two ideas were either that this looks a lot like a convolution, and the second was that the totient function has the following [property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBlbt.png)

[Line I'm stuck on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpWdx.png)

Comment: You should add more context. I doubt the equality can be proved without the definition of $\phi_\omega$, $\omega$ and $\omega*$.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to just must have blanked when writing the post. Updated to include this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following derivation would work if $y(n)$ is zero when $n$ is non-squarefree (which is often the case in sieve problems):

$$
\begin{aligned}
&\sum_{d:d/r|n/r}\mu(d/r){\omega^*(d/r)d/r\over\phi(d/r)}\omega(n/d)=\sum_{t|n/r}\mu(t){\omega^*(t)t\over\phi(t)}\omega\left(n/r\over t\right) \\
&=\omega\left(\frac nr\right)\sum_{t|n/r}\mu(t){\omega^*(t)t\over\phi(t)\omega(t)}
=\omega\left(\frac nr\right)\prod_{p|(n/r)}\left(1-{\omega^*(p)p\over(p-1)\omega(p)}\right) \\
&={\omega(n/r)\over\phi(n/r)}\prod_{p|(n/r)}\left(p-1-{p\omega(p)-p\over\omega(p)}\right)={\omega(n/r)\over\phi(n/r)}\prod_{p|(n/r)}{p-\omega(p)\over\omega(p)}={\phi_\omega(n/r)\over\phi(n/r)}.
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Sorry, what result are you using to convert from the sum to product? I thought to use an Euler product form you need there to be an $n^{-s}$ term with Re(s) >1.

Comment: Never mind I overcomplicated it, you are just using that the sum is also multiplicative. Thanks for the help